# Can I mix Tortoise SVN , Slik Subversion subclipse?

Tags: svn, slik

Wondering if I can use different Subversion clients on the same working files or if the .svn metadata is specific to one type of client. For example, can I check out files in Tortoise or subclipse, and perform some of the tasks using command line Silk Subversion and then commit back again using Tortoise or Subclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use both, Tortoise SVN, and Subclipse - no problem at all. .svn file format does not depend on client; you can use many clients with no fear ;)
And this is quite usable - Subclipse is accessible from Eclipse, so without Eclipse I can use Tortoise; as well as when I got problem with Subclipse, then I update project with Tortoise, just don't forget to refresh that project in Eclipse after changes made by out of Eclipse tool (like Tortoise)

Comment: Subversion was designed to allow this. So yes: use different clients if they help to get your work done. Every subversion client has its pro's and con's, but together they create a really nice toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

this should be no problem, as long as all your svn clients are built against the (roughly) same version of subversion. I use commandline and tortoise on the same working copies. When the command line client is too old, you get the error message "client to old" o_O

Have fun!